# Python Requests - authentication after redirect

Tags: python, authentication, redirect, python-requests

I have a quick question regarding HTTP Basic Authentication after a redirect.

I am trying to login to a website which, for operational reasons, immediately redirects me to a central login site using an HTTP 302 response.  In my testing, it appears that the Requests module does not send my credentials to the central login site after the redirect.  As seen in the code snippet below, I am forced to extract the redirect URL from the response object and attempt the login again.

My question is simply this:
is there a way to force Requests to re-send login credentials after a redirect off-host?

For portability reasons, I would prefer not to use a .netrc file.  Also, the provider of the website has made url_login static but has made no such claim about url_redirect.

Thanks for your time!

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
import requests

url_login = '<url_login>'
myauth = ('<username>', '<password')

login1 = requests.request('get', url_login, auth=myauth)
# this login fails; response object contains the login form information

url_redirect = login1.url
login2 = requests.request('get', url_redirect, auth=myauth)
# this login succeeds; response object contains a welcome message
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a more specific version of the general code above.

- The first `request()` returns an HTTP 200 response and has the form information in its text field.
- The second `request()` returns an HTTP 401 response with `'HTTP Basic: Access denied.'` in its text field.

(Of course, the login succeeds when provided with valid credentials.)

Again, I am wondering whether I can achieve my desired login with only one call to `requests.request()`.

```
import requests

url_login = 'http://cddis-basin.gsfc.nasa.gov/CDDIS_FileUpload/login' 
myauth = ('<username>', '<password>') 

with requests.session() as s: 
    login1 = s.request('get', url_login, auth=myauth) 
    url_earthdata = login1.url 
    login2 = s.request('get', url_earthdata, auth=myauth)
```

Comment: Can you share the url?

Comment: Sure thing -- the URL is 
http://cddis-basin.gsfc.nasa.gov/CDDIS_FileUpload/login, and more details on what I'm trying to do can be found at 
http://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/Data_and_Derived_Products/CDDIS_File_Upload_Documentation.html.

I wanted to keep my question as general as possible, but if this helps, go ahead!

Comment: I think you want a session, are you trying to mimic the curl logic?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to mimic the cURL logic.  In my own implementation, I use a session to handle the cookies.  However, the specific problem I'm curious about (the authentication failure after a re-direct) is not affected by the use of a session object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution to this would be use of "Session". Here is how you can implement Session.

```
import requests

s = requests.session()
url_login = "<loginUrl>"

payload = {
    "username": "<user>",
    "password": "<pass>"
}

req1 = s.post(url_login, data=payload)

# Now to make sure you do not get the "Access denied", use the same session variable for the request.

req2 = s.get(url_earthdata)
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for recommending the use of a Session -- I have updated the example code in my post accordingly.  Unfortunately, the url you reference in your second command, `url_earthdata`, is not known in advance.  The url provided for login, `url_login`, returns an HTTP 302 redirect to an address which is not guaranteed to be static.  I would like to send my credentials to the second URL without explicitly extracting the URL from the first attempt (`url_earthdata = login1.url`) and performing a second attempt (`login2 = s.request('get', url_earthdata, auth=myauth)`)

Comment: in that case, you could use the "allow_redirects=False" in the first request to get the redirecting URL. Just browse through the headers of the first request  for the "url_earthdata" you seek for. For example,
>>> req1 = s.post(url_login, data=payload, allow_redirects=False) 
>>> url_earthdata = req1.headers["<URL_KEY>"]

Comment: Okay, that's a good tip -- but it still requires two separate HTTP queries.  Since I was looking to learn more about re-sending login credentials after a redirect off-host -- i.e., to achieve my login with only one query -- I can accept this answer if you take the focus off Sessions and instead emphasize that "no, you can't do this in one query".  Thanks for your time!

Comment: The point of the HTTP 302 is to perform **URL redirection**. The response with 302 status code provides a redirecting URL on its **header** under **location** key, which is to be triggered by making **another request**. So, **No**, you cannot achieve what you are trying to, through a **single request**.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible with Requests, by design. The issue stems from a security vulnerability, where if an attacker modifies the redirect URL *and* the credentials are automatically sent to the redirect URL, then the credentials are compromised. So, credentials are stripped from redirect calls.

There's a thread about this on github:
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2949