# Python requests authentication after redirect result 401

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests

I have question regarding HTTP Basic Authentication after a redirect.
I am trying to login to a website which redirects me to a login site (HTTP 302 response).

```
 import requests    
 response = requests.get('my_url')

 if response.history:
     print("Request was redirected")
     for resp in response.history:
         print(resp.status_code, resp.url)
     print("Final destination:")
     print(response.status_code, response.url)
 else:
     print("Request was not redirected")
```

The output:

```
 Request was redirected
 302 my_url
 Final destination:
 401 new_url
```

The new_url is url where I should put username and password. I tried solution from here: [stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945057/python-requests-authentication-after-redirect) but it didn't work for me - I always get response:

```
Out[152]: <Response [401]>
```

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For this type of things I usually use selenium to fill out the form for me in the browser, and then I save the cookie in a requests session. If the other answer does not help, or if you do not want to try selenium, maybe you can log in manually first and paste in the cookie to the session?

Comment: @PaxVobiscum  It's part of scrip which should run every day without user and send something to "my_url" so I can't log in manually.

Comment: Would you consider using selenium?

Comment: @PaxVobiscum I'm just going to read something about it.

Comment: Okay, I created a small gist about it here if you want additional info https://gist.github.com/rloqvist/9002467a09ecdef56e97e9cc41daee65

Comment: very good question. I am banging my head on the wall for this as well.
Its about how to get the Authentication header into the redirected request.
My first idea was to use the hooks provided in python requests, however, they are only for responses currently :(

Selenium is not a good solution for an adaptor querying a port.