# How can I open login page with redirects in session with Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I have function for auth in a resource and save in session and reuse it in other functions. But the resource were transfered to another link and changed host. After that my function doesn't work correctly

So, my code:

```
import requests

class ExampleClass(object):
    def __init__(self, login, password):
        self.login = login
        self.password = password
        self.session = None
        self.headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
                        'acept': '*/*'}
        self.resource_auth()

    def resource_auth(self):
        old_link = 'https://www.old_example.ru/auth/oid/new/?next=/'
        new_link = 'https://www.new_example.ru/auth/oid/new/?next=/'
        self.session = requests.session()
        self.session.auth = (self.login, self.password)
        self.session.headers = self.headers
        # response = self.session.get(old_link)  # worked
        response = self.session.get(new_link)    # doesn't work
        assert response.status_code == 200, "Error: {}".format(response.content)
```

When I open `new_link` by myself in browser I have some redirects (with `old_link` I have no redirects) and after them I get page with login form and button. Difference between `new_link` and `old_link` only in links and hosts, login form and button the same.
I have got source page when open `new_link` by script and looks like the script doesn't have time to go to final page with login form.
Also I've tried to use `response = self.session.get(new_link, allow_redirects=True)` and it doesn't help, tried to use `response = session.post(new_link)` and it also doesn't help
I've tried to add time delay and it also doesn't help

Could anyone help with understanding what's wrong?

**Additional info:** The code runs by bot on build machine. I don't run it local

Comment: Not sure if this will work on Python 2.7, but with 3.9 I have working code that after every request pickles the session cookies to save to a file, and when starting a new session unpickles the file to update the new session’s cookies - this restores the authentication for as long as the authentication timeout, in my case two hours.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests - authentication after redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945057/python-requests-authentication-after-redirect) -- See https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2949 -- Quote: This isn't possible with Requests, by design. The issue stems from a security vulnerability, where if an attacker modifies the redirect URL and the credentials are automatically sent to the redirect URL, then the credentials are compromised. So, credentials are stripped from redirect calls.

Comment: @DanielF, I'll check this solution and reply back, thanks a lot!